# HTML Special Characters and PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, special-characters

I have a span that contains and upper arrow: `&#9650;`

Via an AJAX call, in PHP, I receive a POST parameter that contains this arrow.

```
$("#mySpan").click(function(){

      var arrow = $(this).html();
      alert(arrow); //displays the arrow the in an alert box
      $.post('Something.php',{ arrow: arrow },function(data){
            alert(data);
      });

});
```

In PHP, I am simply checking if the parameter is this arrow.

```
if(isset($_POST['arrow']){

      $arrow = $_POST['arrow'];
      if($arrow=='&#9650;')
            echo 'Its an arrow';
      else
            echo 'Its not an arrow';
}
```

The JS returns an alert box 'Its not an arrow'. Am I comparing it in the right way?

Comment: you might need to use something like urldecode

Comment: Check which data is sent via ajax and check what you have in `$_POST['arrow']`

Comment: @MatRt the alert before the ajax call displays the arrow, and if I do `echo $arrow;` and then do a JS alert it shows the arrow as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(this).html();` returns the actual Unicode character `▲` instead of the character escape `&#9650;`.

You can check the length to see this:

```
alert($(this).html().length); // => 1
```

Next, you send this character to the backend. And all AJAX data is encoded as UTF-8. UTF-8 representation of `▲` is `E2 96 B2`.

```
echo $_POST['arrow'] === "\xE2\x96\xB2"; // Its an arrow
```

Comment: Or `echo $_POST['arrow'] === '▲';`, if you save the source code as UTF-8.

Comment: That worked thanks, but there's something weird, if I use `"\xE2\x96\xB2"` in the comparison, it works, if i use `'\xE2\x96\xB2'`, it doesn't..

Comment: @Ali Bassam, PHP will interpret `\x..` sequences only in double quotes. In single quotes only \' and \\ are recognized. http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php